# How to mavenize a standard eclipse project but only for some dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have an existing eclipse project with standard dependencies in the classpath. I need to add a new dependency through maven but the rest of the dependencies need to stay there as jars bundled with the project.

I am using [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), if I right click on the project --> maven --> enable maven, a pom file is created. At this stage I can add my new dependency through the pom file but all the existing dependencies seem to be gone from the classpath.

Hence the question: **Is there a way to create a hybrid project that has both standard dependencies and maven dependencies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your legacy dependencies by using the scope "system" (and the tag "systemPath") ?

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you should even attempt to create such a thing, and I don't know why you would want to.

If you want to use Maven, then you should define all your dependencies in your pom so that a maven build will actually work.  If all your dependencies aren't defined, how do you expect maven to build your project?

You need to decide which means of dependency resolution you want to use instead of trying to mix two together.

Comment: I appreciate it's not ideal, my question was: can it be done? :)

Comment: I find it amusing that I get downvotes for saying to use Maven for all dependency management, yet the upvoted and accepted answer is to use Maven for all dependency management.  I know it is a better answer than mine, as it does say how to actually do it, but none the less, mine doesn't contradict it either.